# Elastic cloud - unable to create index

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

I am trying to use elastic cloud hosted elasticsearch service https://www.elastic.co/cloud

I am using python and elasticsearch-py package to connect in my flaks app:

```
es_connection = Elasticsearch(
   ["https://myuser:mysecret@xxxxxxx.us-west-1.aws.found.io:9243"]
) 

es_connection.indices.create(index="myindex", ignore=400, body=mapping_dict)
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
08:55:56,240 elasticsearch DEBUG    < {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"security_exception","reason":"action [indices:admin/create] is unauthorized for user [myuser]"}],"type":"security_exception","reason":"action [indices:admin/create] is unauthorized for user [myuser]"},"status":403}
```

In the shield editor, I have set this role for these users as:

```
admin: admin
myuser: admin
```

and these roles are defined in the editor as
   // This is the editor for all the roles.
   // Following are some sample roles. To actually use a role, map a user in the above editor.

// Admins can do everything

```
 admin:
 cluster: all
 indices:
   '*': all
```

This means, `myuser` is set to `admin` role, so it should be able to create index..right? so why am I getting error?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by putting both usernames in the same line. Like this:

`admin: admin, myuser`